# Fair vs NonFair

Tags: java, multithreading

I have been tested fair and non fair disciplines via `RentrantLock`. I wrote a small program that simulates dinning philosophers.

Each philospher has left and right fork which are `ReentrantLock`s. I have simulated 1000 times act of thinking and eating:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < ACT_TIMES; i++) {
            act();
        }
```

where `act` is

```
private void act() {
        think();
        eat();

    }
```

`Think` is not interesting it just sleeps for some amount of time. Here is `eat` method

```
private void eat() {
        try {
            if (left.tryLock(0, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)) {
                if (right.tryLock(0, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)) {
                    log("eating");
                    eatCount++;
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(EAT_TIME);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    } finally {
                        left.unlock();
                        right.unlock();
                    }
                } else {
                    left.unlock();
                }
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Main method:

```
 Lock[] forks = new Lock[5];
        for (int i = 0; i < forks.length; i++) {
            forks[i] = new ReentrantLock();
        }
        Philosopher p1 = new Philosopher(0, forks[1], forks[0]);
        Philosopher p2 = new Philosopher(1, forks[2], forks[1]);
        Philosopher p3 = new Philosopher(2, forks[3], forks[2]);
        Philosopher p4 = new Philosopher(3, forks[4], forks[3]);
        Philosopher p5 = new Philosopher(4, forks[0], forks[4]);
        ExecutorService exec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
        exec.submit(p1);
        exec.submit(p2);
        exec.submit(p3);
        exec.submit(p4);
        exec.submit(p5);
```

After all 5 threads finishes, I print eatCount for each philosopher. And these values don't differ too much for fair(`new ReentrantLock(true)`) and unfair(`new ReentrantLock()`) discipline.

(first number is a number of a philospher)

Fair lock:

```
0 344
1 348
2 366
3 359
4 363
Total number of eating 1780
```

Unfair Lock:

```
0 338
1 338
2 339
3 341
4 352
Total number of eating 1708
```

I have expected some starvation for unfair lock, I mean some philosopher/philosophers have to have eatCount much greater than others, but starvation didn't happen. why?

Comment: Can you post your whole code?

Comment: I think this question reflects a deep misunderstanding of concurrency problems.  They don't happen all the time, even in a program that has a concurrency bug; they only happen at 3AM Saturday mornings, or whenever the worst possible time is.

Comment: You have not only starvation, but also deadlock possible - after all grab left forks. Also, what Louis said.

Comment: @zch Not sure why you think it could deadlock. If a thread can't acquire both locks it releases the one that was acquired, if any.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the active waiting (usually bad idea) part. So it's not deadlock, but it's still possible that the philosophers will keep left forks, leaving them on table for so short that nobody else could touch them. So you still have starvation.

Comment: @Louis as I ask here this question, so I see such beahviour after many runs

Comment: @zch as javadoc says fair lock guarantees that thread will act in queue order

Comment: @maks - scenario I'm talking about: 1. everybody grabs left 2. everybody fails to grab right 3. everybody releases left and back to 1.. There is no lock fairness guarantee that can prevent this.

Comment: @zch sure, there is small probability of such situation, but my question is not about absolutely correct solution of dinning philosophers problem, but about fairness and unfairness

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The thread which releases a lock has a much better chance of regaining the lock as it is busy while the other threads could be blocked.  Busy waiting won't show this as each thread will have an equal chance of grabbing the lock.  Possibly the one to release the lock could be at a slight disadvantage.

```
final ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    final int finalI = i;
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                lock.lock();
                System.out.println("locked by " + finalI);
                lock.unlock();
            }
        }
    }).start();
}
```

prints

```
locked by 0
locked by 0
locked by 0
locked by 0
locked by 0
locked by 1
locked by 1
locked by 1
locked by 1
locked by 1
locked by 2
locked by 2
locked by 2
locked by 2
locked by 2
locked by 3
locked by 3
locked by 3
locked by 3
locked by 3
locked by 4
locked by 4
locked by 4
locked by 4
locked by 4
```

but if I make the lock fair with true I see

```
locked by 0
locked by 1
locked by 2
locked by 3
locked by 4
locked by 0
locked by 1
locked by 2
locked by 3
locked by 4
locked by 0
locked by 1
locked by 2
locked by 3
locked by 4
locked by 0
locked by 1
locked by 2
locked by 3
locked by 4
locked by 0
locked by 1
locked by 2
locked by 3
locked by 4
```

Answer (score 1):

remove all `sleep()`, you may see some unfairness.

Answer (score 0):

@Maks, have you tried setting random values for EAT_TIME?

This might bring some unfairness to the logic.